# Laptop screen brightness after restarting

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, display

I have a Compaq laptop and using Windows 7.

when I change the display brightness for example to 80% and then restart the system, after restarting the display gets dim again and I have to move around the brightness bar again.

Is it hardware problem or what?

Comment: Is this with the laptop plugged in or on battery power?

Comment: both of them ..

Comment: And just happens in restart, but in hibernate or sleep, there is no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, Seems the problem was in [Display Color Calibration](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Calibrate-your-display).
Now there is no problem, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

It might be your adaptive brightness adjusting automatically, at which point you can check out this info page on the Windows site to turn it off: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Adjust-your-monitors-brightness-and-contrast